# Получить значения даты и времени в int

Tags: python

Возьмем к примеру текущую дату в unix 1638518160, далее мне нужно из нее извлечь отдельно число (сегодня 3е), и время в в часах и секундах,

Это можно сделать через strftime, но полученные значения нельзя преобразовать в int.

Каким способом это реализовать?

Comment: Что значит "нельзя"? А что мешает? `int(xxx.strftime("%d"))` или просто `xxx.day`. `import datetime
datetime.date.fromtimestamp(1638518160).day`

Comment: Почему это сегодня третье? Кое-где ещё второе. Так что когда говорите про дату из unixtimestamp стоит всегда уточнять часовой пояс

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime


unix_time = 1638518160
dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix_time)

print(dt.day)  # 3
print(dt.hour)  # 7
print(dt.second)  # 0
```